# Trying to Extend the One2many Field Widget

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I've trying to extend the One2Many Field Widget in Odoo
This is my code in Javascript

```
 openerp.bahia_personnel_management = function (instance) {
    instance.web.form.custom_widgets.add('one2many_remove_spec_columns','instance.bahia_personnel_management.one2many_remove_spec_columns');
    instance.bahia_personnel_management.one2many_remove_spec_columns = instance.web.form.FieldOne2Many.extend({
    _start: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        throw "YAHOO"
    }
});};
```

As you can see in my javascript right now I've only throw first an Exception to test if my widget is really working, btw my purpose of my widget is to remove a specific Table Header, here's my code in XML with tagging of my customize widget.

```
<field name="employee_checklists_documents_list" string ="" widget = "one2many_remove_spec_columns">
<tree class = "oe_checklist_bahia"  editable="top/bottom" create = "false" limit = "500"> <!-- class = "oe_checklist_bahia"  string = ""-->
    <field name="param_name_1"  readonly = "1" />
    <field name="param_name_1_value"   attrs="{'invisible': [('param_name_1_value_visible', '=', False)]}"/>
    <field name="param_name_1_check"  string = "" attrs="{'invisible': [('param_name_1_check_visible', '=', False)]}"/>
    <field name="param_name_1_value_visible" invisible = "1"  />
    <field name="param_name_1_check_visible" invisible = "1"  />
</tree>
```

Other Parameters needed in calling a customized widget

1. Calling the Javascript file directory in my XML Done.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend a filed 
I am running in odoo 9

```
odoo.define('yvonne', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    //enter code here

var FieldMany2One = core.form_widget_registry.get('many2one');

    FieldMany2One.include({
        init: function(field_manager, node) {
            console.log(" many 2 one init");
            this._super(field_manager, node);
            this.limit = 10
        },
    });
}
```

I hope this work for you

Comment: The purpose of the widget is to remove a specific Table Header!